# R: How do I create a correlation matrix with time series of different lengths, and truncate longer time series based on the shorter time series?

Tags: r, matrix, time-series, correlation

Set-up:
I have 50 monthly time series of 50 distinct items, from Jan 2015 to July 2023.
Some of the time series are completely populated, with data from Jan 2015 to July 2023.
However, some other time series are lagged -- i.e. starting sometimes in July 2015 ending in July 2023 or starting in Jan 2018 and ending in July 2023. All time series end in July 2023, but some may have data that starts earlier.

My issue is that when I create a correlation matrix between the fully populated time series (i.e. Jan 2015 to July 2023) against the lagged start time series (i.e. July 2018 to July 2023), the correlation is biased because it runs correlations against the parts of the time series not included in the lagged start time series (i.e. Jan 2015 - July 2018).

I want the correlation to run against the truncated version of the fully populated time series depending on when the lagged start time series starts. For example, if the lagged start time series starts in July 2018, I want all the values between Jan 2015 and July 2018 to be cut off from the fully populated time series, and then for the correlation to be run between the truncated time series and the lagged start time series.

I'm not sure how to do this however, because for there are multiple different lagged starts, and for some time series, it isn't just the case of lagged start, but there are 1-2 month periods of holes in the data. How would I approach this issue?

Here is the code I've tried so far. Obviously have not tried in truncating of the longer time series yet, because I'm not sure how to approach this problem. The 2 approaches are a dataset with the lagged start time series with 0's plugged in for values before the lagged start, and with "" plugged in for values before the lagged start. The method with 0 just treats 0 like a number in the time series, and biases my correlation. The method with "" produces NAs for the correlations run against those series.

```
    #First attempt of correlations. Method: Compare running correlations with csv with
    #no zeroes and with zeroes in the time series to see if the correlation is smart enough to run   properly  
    # and automatically truncate the fully populated time series.

    #Results: The correlation across no zeroes produces all NAs. 
    #        The correlation w/ zeroes takes the whole time series, including the zeroes. 

    #Import files of monthly series with zeros and without zeros to test if corellation function runs   differently
    monthly <- read.csv('xxx.csv',header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    monthly.nozeroes <- read.csv('xxx No Zeros.csv',header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    #Take out the first column
    monthly <- monthly[,-1]
    monthly.nozeroes <- monthly.nozeroes[,-1]


    #Simple pairwise correlation
    cor.monthly <- cor(monthly, method="pearson")
    write.csv(cor.monthly, "PearsonPairwiseCorr_monthly.csv")

    cor.monthly.nozeroes <- cor(monthly.nozeroes, method="pearson")
    write.csv(cor.monthly.nozeroes, "PearsonPairwiseCorr_monthly.nozeroes.csv")
```